# Подключение библиотеки к проекту Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Создаю динамическую библиотеку с помощью Qt. Собираю её, в итоге у меня 4 файла:

3 ссылки на библиотеку.

1. libfigure.so
2. libfigure.so.1
3. libfigure.so.1.0

И сама библиотека.

4. libfigure.so.1.0.0

Создаю новый проект и подключаю библиотеку через меню(Добавить библиотеку - Внешнюю... - Выбираю библиотеку и заголовочные файлы). Вот .pro файл:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = libDemo
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-figure-Desktop_Qt_Debug/ -lfigure

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../figure
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../figure
```

При запуске программы из Qt Creator все работает.
Но при запуске в терминале :

./libDemo: error while loading shared libraries: libfigure.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Куда надо положить библиотеку что бы программа запускалась из терминала?

Comment: В тот же каталог что и ELF пробовали класть?

Comment: Клал рядом с основной программой все 4 файла. Тот же эффект.

Comment: Хм... libfigure.so.1 есть в каталоге с ELFом и libfigure.so.1указывает на libfigure.so.1.0.0, при этом по этому пути libfigure.so.1.0.0 есть? Тогда мистика непонятная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - **/usr/local/lib**.
После размещения библиотеки следует под суперпользователем выполнить команду **ldconfig**.

Можно в **/usr/lib** но не стоит, лучше не засорять этот каталог вручную.

Так же библиотеки можно размещать рядом с основной программой.
В этом случае команде ldconfig следует указать путь по которому находится библиотека:

```
ldconfig <path>
```

Где бы не размещалась библиотека, после каждой ее сборки, необходимо выполнять команду ldconfig.

Comment: Это помогло. Но почему библиотека сама не подхватывается, как в Windows?

Comment: Видимо потому, что именно так устроены UNIX-подобные ОС. Если необходимо автоматическое подхватывание, то можно отслеживать изменения в нужных директориях с помощью команды inotify и при обнаружении таковых запускать ldconfig.

Answer (score 2):

Также можете дописать в /etc/ld.so.conf путь к вашей библиотеке и выполнить ldconfig после её сборки. Кстати, вызывать ldconfig после каждой пересборки - это лишнее, достаточно вызвать его один раз после первой сборки вашей библиотеки, чтобы она попала в список динамически подключаемых библиотек, находящихся в системе.
Или можете модифицировать переменную окружения LD_LIBRARY_PATH при запуске приложения: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/your/library" ./your_app`