# Как тянуть стандартные библиотеки из произвольного места

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Пишу под линукс в `Qt5`.Как сделать так,что бы проект тянул библиотеки стандартные(`Qt5Gui`,`Qt5Core`...) из произвольного места?
Например из директории выше

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453594/178576), [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498189/178576), [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670096/178576)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать так,что бы проект тянул библиотеки  из произвольного
>   места?

Библиотечные функции подключаются к исполнимому модулю на этапе линковки. Поэтому, ответ зависит от того, как Вы линкуете программу.

Если Вы всё пишите сами, в командной строке, то нужно использовать ключ -L <каталог с библиотеками>. Например так:

```
g++ my_prog.cpp -L Путь_к_библиотекам_QT
```

Если Ваш проект собирается с помощью cmake, то нужно использовать оператор:

```
add_compile_options(-L Путь_к_библиотекам_QT)
```

Если же пишите makefile сами, то наиболее корректным путём будет использование оператора

```
LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs Qt5Gui`
```

в Вашем Makefile.